# Wordpress site has clone from diffrent url

Tags: php, wordpress, security, curl, bots

Well, I have a WordPress site. Today when I checked the Google traffic reports, I caught a backlink from a different URL. After I checked the URL, I was shocked: somebody copied my web site!

I think "it" used curl or `file_get_contents()`. And after getting page, it changed my URL to its URL.

Already, Google created indexes of this URL.

How can I block this access from this "bot"?

Note: I checked db access and file permissions, it is fine.

- When I closed server, clone site closed.
- When I add publish new content, clone site also does it.
- When I change theme file codes, clone site changes.

Comment: Properly add a `server_name` attribute to your server configuration block. Someone is impersonating your domain and it's probably due to a leak in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with wordpress, but, it seems like that this 'bot' copied your front-end and then using your API to function in the same way.

This below is guessing on what the other site's owner is trying to do:

If you have a login site, then I think the copy site's owner tries to phishing on the login data, then try to use it to get sensitive information from other sites with the same login data - since a lot of people has the same user-password pairs on every site.

If this is the case, the first thing you should do is to make sure that this site wont show up in [any search engines](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en).

In the same situation I would try to figure out what is the IP/domain of the copy site and then put set up firewall rules to block all of the request from there. With this you can't really prevent the users to enter their login info to that site, but hacking is done by programmers, so if you are lucky then your clients/users data wont be saved in the phishing database. This only happens if the phishing layer is putting the user-pwd into the database only if the login is successful. But it's more likely that there is a successful and IP field in the phishing DB too, so the spams can be filtered.

If the "phisher" is not saving IP field then the last thing you can do is to ruin the phishing database. For this you need to get the IP of the other site, and filter your incoming request. If the sender of the request has the other site's IP address, then instead of checking the login permission you should just send back a similar response, that you used to send, when one successfully logs in to your site. With this each successful and unsuccessful login will look the same in the phishing database. This still belongs to the defense category. Spamming the phishing database counts as attacking, so I don't recommend that.

By default the user's should be able to realize if their data is being phished, but as we know it's not used to happen, however you can't help much on the realization skills.

If you don't have any login page, then the situations is not that bad.

Copying a website is illegal, so you can do [a lot more](https://www.impactbnd.com/blog/remove-stolen-website-duplicate-content)